# How do I add a custom button to Outlook's reminders dialog?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a custom Outlook AddIn, and would like to add a custom button to the reminders dialog, like Skype for business does with their meetings.

[Example of Skype's "Join Online" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p5MF.png)

[Example of where I'd like my custom button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySalc.png)

I would like the ability for the user to click the custom button and a dynamic  web page to load (https://example.com/appt/123)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no officially supported way to do that. You can of course hack something using straight Windows API on the HWND level. I don't think you'd be able to do that in .Net.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Skype must be doing this via the Windows API then? I know when I create a Skype meeitng, it seems to use the same reminder dialog as non-skype meetings.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jenstr/2013/04/08/join-button-missing-on-lync-meetings-from-federated-partners/